# Passing information from AspNetcore controller to AspNet(.NET Framework) controller

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I have 2 MVC .net projects:

**Controller 1** is located on a netcoreapp3.1 project.
It is used to load summary information about a city each time a city is selected in top bar.

[image]

It involves VUE (that is why i am not so sure of how to send **city** input to other controller), and whenever a city is selected it will call next code, which will only refresh summary information (in red) and not the whole page :

```
   [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index([FromQuery]int city)
    {
        if (!_citiesService.CanAccessCity(city))
            return Forbid();

        var pueblo = await _puebloRepository.GetBySharedCityId(city);
        if (pueblo == null) throw new Exception("City doesn't exist");
        var cuadrosDeMando = await _cuadroRepository.GetAllAsync(pueblo.ID_PUEBLO);

        return Ok(new SummaryDTO
        {
            CuadrosDeMando = cuadrosDeMando.Count(),
            PotenciaInstalada = pueblo.POT_INSTALADA,
            Encendidos = cuadrosDeMando.Count(cdm => cdm.EncendidoApagado),
            SinComunicacion = cuadrosDeMando.Count(cdm => cdm.Estado == CuadroDeMandoEstado.SinComunicacion),
            Alarmas = cuadrosDeMando.Count(cdm => cdm.Estado == CuadroDeMandoEstado.Alarma)
        });
    }
```

**Controller 2** is located on .net Framework 4.5.2 project

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Map", city);
        }
```

It will be called when user clicks on **Alumbrado Público** window:
[image]

I want value of **city** in  controller 2, to be the input **city** value of controller 1.

So steps are:

1. Controller 1 is called
2. After clicking the window, controller 2 is called

I have tryed:

1. Setting a cookie in controller 1:

   ```
   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpResponse.Cookies.Append(
                "city",
                city,
                new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieOptions()
                {
                    Path = "/",
                   Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60),
                   IsEssential = true
                }
            );
   ```

But cookie is not correctly set (or at least i can not see it browser cookie repository)

2. Passing info through tempdata:
   TempData["city"] = city;

But i can not access it in controller2 as TempData["city"] will be null

Any workaround suggested?

Comment: Add `city` as a parameter to your .NET Framework action, and pass it via the querystring.

Comment: Problem is that i do not know where city is coming from. VS will not redirect me to controller1 method invocation, as it is something vue does through some middleware which i am not sure about.